# How to correctly impose a background-color to a div wrapping article and aside in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want to give a background color for the portion covered by the `article` and the `aside` only, so i can give the impression that the `aside` has the same height as the `article` ( basically giving the same background color for the `aside` and the `div` wrapping both `aside` and `article`)

```
       <div style="background-color:#cccccc" class="clear_fix">
         <p> This is where the container starts !!!</p>
         <p> Why the div stops here ???!!!!</p>
         <article>
            <h2> Meanwhile, Let's learn about Tesla </h2>
            <p>Tesla's achievements and his abilities as a showman</p>
         </article>
         <aside>
            <h2> Brand-new and Used cars </h2>
            <p> Buy your first car starting from 0.99 $.</p>
         </aside>
      </div>
```

Here is the style.css related to the tags above.

```
article {
width:716px;
background-color:#87ceeb;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #a9a9a9;
padding-top:20px;
float:left;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
aside {
width:240px;
float:left;
padding-top:20px;
background-color:#fff5dd;
margin-top:4px;
margin-left:4px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 4px 4px #a9a9a9;
}
.clear_fix {
clear:both;
}
```

But what i get, is that the background color of the `div` only affects the two first `p` tags.

[image]

Obviously, this is not what i intended to do by wrapping everything with a `div`.

Do you have an idea why the `div` background color in my case does not extend below the `article and the`aside` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Something does not make sense, is there a style sheet? I am wondering about floats and absolute positioning...

Comment: yeah.  can we see the CSS?

Comment: Sure, i'll edit the page one second!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you floated the `<article>` and the `<aside>` elements, they are out of the flow of the parent `<div>`.

To the style of the parent element, add the following property: `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`.

```
<div style="background-color:#cccccc; overflow: auto;" class="clear_fix">
```

### Why This Works

The reason the `overflow` property does the trick stems from how the CSS block formatting model works.

Specifically, the relevant specification is:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p>Some text...</p>
    <div class="floated">Floated text</div>
</div>
```

In the **Basic Case**, all of these elements are in normal flow (no floats) and are formatted within the "block formatting context" defined by the root element of the page.  So, they basically fill up the width of the page and, being block elements, are stacked one on top of the other.

Consider **Case 1**, in which we float `.floated`.  The floated element is no longer in normal flow and it is positioned to the left edge of the parent container and adjacent to the bottom of the paragraph, which is the nearest block level element to the floated element.

The border of the parent element wraps around the normal flow child elements which is why the floated elements juts out (remember, the floated element is ignored when formatting the normal flow elements, which determines the height of the parent container).

Now, in **Case 2**, let's float `.wrap`.  In this case, the parent element shrinks-to-fit the content, including both the `<p>` AND the `.floated` child.  This is because `div.wrap` has now established a new **block formatting context** and as specified by the CSS rules, must enclosed all the edges of the boxes that it contains (including floats).

Finally, in **Case 3**, we declare `overflow: hidden` on `.wrap` in normal flow (not floated).  Setting `overflow` to any value other than `visible` starts a new block formatting context.  As such, `.wrap` still extends the full width of the page AND it now also contains all the edges of any floated child elements, so the border wraps around the floated element.

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/VXL4B/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved the problem ! But i don't understand why it get solved this way ? Can you explain please ?

Comment: I take this for granted, but let me look up in the CSS spec so that I can post a decent and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your `clear_fix` class isn't doing its job.

Check out this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eq85z/2/show/) which just toggles the  `clearfix` class on the container element. When `clearfix` isn't set, it looks a lot like what you are experiencing.

Use this css for the `clearfix` class:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```